# Can't wakeup Raspberry Pi if unused for more than a day

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

Folks at the Raspberry Pi board forwarded me over here.

I'm using Raspberry Pi to run Onion Share and ProtonVPN on a CanaKit Raspberry Pi 4. I check it once a day. Moving the mouse wakes it up. But if I miss a day, moving the mouse does not wake it up. Likewise for the keyboard. It doesn't matter what USB ports they are plugged into. And trying to access via BlueTooth also doesn't help. So I have to unplug it and boot up again.

Any idea how I can avoid having to unplug it and can just keep waking it up by moving the mouse?

Thanks!

Comment: Du you run a desktop environment? If so, which?

Comment: have you any way of remote access through `ssh` (other computer) ? iy so, you can check misc. files in `/var/log` to have a clue.

Comment: Thanks! Yes. I am running a desktop environment: it's Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster). I do nave another computer, but I'm pretty new to Linux, so I haven't learned to SSH yet (other than for setting up the Raspberry Pi, if I recall correctly). Thanks again!

Comment: Any other suggestions out there? Thanks!